# Minimal cover of functional dependency

Tags: database, relational-database, normalization, functional-dependencies

I am having trouble with this textbook question

Consider the set of functional dependencies F = { A → B, B → C, CD → A, AC → D }

Compute a minimal cover of F.

Am trying to follow the simple steps to do so. First I can see there is no right hand singleton to do. Is it possible to single out CD and AC on the left hand side? Do I have to?

This is my attempt at it, not following the steps approach. Is it correct?

```
F = { A→ B, B→C, CD→A, AC → D}
=> F = { A → C, CD → A, AC → D}
=> F = { CD → C, AC → D}
=> F = { D→ C, AC → D}
=> F = {AC → C}
=> F = {A->C}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your notation, the minimal cover contains only `A→C`, but this is certainly not a cover of the starting `F`, since many dependencies in `F` cannot be derived from the single dependency `A→C`. For example, how could you derive `A→B`from `A→C`? In the minimal cover you “simplify” the set of functional dependencies without loosing information.

So, let's start from the beginning and see how one should proceed to obtain the minimal cover.

First you should rewrite the dependencies with more than one attribute on the right hand and, as you note, this is not necessary.

Then, for each dependence that has more than one attribute on the left, we should see if some of them can be eliminated. There are only two cases, `CD→A` and `AC→D`. The check is performed in this way. An attribute can be eliminated if the closure of the other attribute with respect to `F` include the right hand. So we have to calculate both C+ and D+ for the first dependence, and A+ and C+ for the second one.

```
C⁺ = {C}
D⁺ = {D}
```

Both closure do not contain `A`, so the dependence `CD→A` must be maintained.

```
A⁺ = {A, B, C, D}
C⁺ = {C}
```

Since the closure of the attribute `A` contains `D`, `C` can be eliminated from the left hand, and the new set of dependencies is:

```
F' = {A→B, B→C, CD→A, A→D}
```

At this point we need to check if any functional dependence can be eliminated, by calculating the closure of the left part with respect to the *other* dependencies, and see if this closure contains the right hand part.

```
A⁺ = AD
B⁺ = B
CD⁺ = CD
A⁺ = ABC
```

In no case the closure contains the right hand, so that the minimal cover of `F` is `F'`.